# Simple text file formatter crashes under Linux, but fine in Windows

Tags: c++

I've made a simple .acf file to .json file formatter. But for some reason it runs correctly under Windows with GCC using msys2 - But after executing a string insert or replace - it segmentation faults every time.

What it does is convert the below file into a json compatible format. It appends commas after each entry, applies attribute set symbol and puts braces around it.

Save as test.acf:

```
"AppState"
{
    "appid"         "730"
    "Universe"              "1"
    "name"          "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"
    "StateFlags"            "4"
    "installdir"            "Counter-Strike Global Offensive"
    "LastUpdated"           "1462547468"
    "UpdateResult"          "0"
    "SizeOnDisk"            "14990577143"
    "buildid"               "1110931"
    "LastOwner"             "76561198013962068"
    "BytesToDownload"               "8768"
    "BytesDownloaded"               "8768"
    "AutoUpdateBehavior"            "1"
    "AllowOtherDownloadsWhileRunning"               "0"
    "UserConfig"
    {
            "Language"              "english"
    }
    "MountedDepots"
    {
            "731"           "205709710082221598"
            "734"           "5169984513691014102"
    }
}
```

Minimal main code with defects triple slashed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    file.open("test.acf");
    std::string data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    int indexQuote = 0;
    int index[4];
    int insertCommaNext = -1;
    string delims = "\"{}"; // It skips between braces and quotes only
    std::size_t found = data.find_first_of(delims);
    while(found != std::string::npos)
    {
      int inc = 1; // 0-4 depending on the quote - 0"key1" 2"value3" 4{
      char c = data.at(found);

      if (c != '"') {
        if (c == '}')
          insertCommaNext = found + 1; // Record index to insert comma after (following closing brace)
        else if (c == '{') {
          ///data.insert(index[1] + 1, ":");
          ///inc++;
        }

        indexQuote = 0;
      } else {
        if (insertCommaNext != -1) {
          ///data.insert(insertCommaNext, ",");
          ///inc++;
          insertCommaNext = -1;
        }

        index[indexQuote] = found;

        if (indexQuote == 2) { // Join 'key: value' by placing the comma
          ///data.replace(index[1] + 1, 1, ":");
        } else if (indexQuote == 4) { // Add comma after each key/value entry
          indexQuote = 0;
          ///data.insert(index[3] + 1, ",");
          ///inc++;
        }

        indexQuote++;
      }

      found = data.find_first_of(delims, found + inc);
    }

    data = "{" + data + "}";
}
```

If you uncomment any of the triple slashed /// lines - containing an insert/replace, it will crash.

I'm certian the code quality is not great, there's probably better ways to achieve this. Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or one of the sanitizers?  Asan (add `-fsanitize=address` to your cflags) would probably catch this right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `indexQuote` gets higher than 3, so `index[indexQuote] = found;` goes out of bounds. You have the case below that resets `indexQuote` to 0, you have to do that before you try to call `index[indexQuote]`.

For reference, I debugged this by adding prints everywhere and printing all the variables until I found where it crashed.

Comment: Ugh, sprinkling code with print statements isn't a good debugging habit to get into, learn to use a debugger and generally for crashes the debugger will stop exactly on the line of code that causes the problem

Comment: Cheers for that. As it worked on Windows - It never occurred to me that such a thing would happen. Weird.

Comment: @AlanBirtles - nothing wrong with debugging with sprinkled `printf` (or `fprintf(stderr, ....)` ) statements. You can even wrap them in `#ifdef DEBUG` preprocessor conditionals, and have them for later use should a code addition cause problems or a regression.